# List users except current user using wp_dropdown_user?

Tags: plugins

I am creating a plugin where I need to select other users except me(current user who is logged in).

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

wp_dropdown_users(array(
    'name' => 'user',
    'exclude' => '$user_id,1',
    'show' => 'user_login'
));
```

is not providing required result. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
'exclude' => '$user_id,1',
```

This will generate the string '$user_id,1', it won't insert the user ID into your string.

The reason for this is the difference between '$hello' and "$hello" E.g.

```
$hello = 5;
echo '$hello'; // prints out $hello
echo "$hello"; // prints out 5
```

So using double rather than single quotes would fix your issue.

### An even more reliable way

Use string concatenation to tie them together instead, e.g:

```
'exclude' => $user_id.',1',
```

The . operator joins two strings together, e.g.:

```
echo 'Hello there '.$firstname.', my name is '.$myname;
```

### A more generic way

Use an array, and use `implode` to generate the string

```
$excluded_users = array();
$excluded_users[] = 1;
$excluded_users[] = $user_id;
// .. etc
'exclude' => implode( ',' , $excluded_users )
```

**I recommend you read up on magic quotes in basic PHP and string handling**

Comment: Just as additional information, there is a nice [answer on PHP strings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/2505105) over at [so] that is worth reading. @Gunaseelan